# What are the differences between WPINC and ABSPATH?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

It's common for plugin developers to protect their plugins from direct access. I saw two ways to do that:

```
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) die;
```

and

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;
```

What are the differences between WPINC and ABSPATH? Which one is the 'right' way to do it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They are defined as follows:

```
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/' );
define( 'WPINC', 'wp-includes' );
```

`dirname` is a PHP function that returns the path of the parent directory, and  `wp-includes` is pretty self explanatory.

I would say `ABSPATH` is better because it's one of the first things WP loads and it also looks better:) But there is no real "right way" because they both work.

Comment: There is no real right way, and I always use `if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;`... but, maybe, consider that the scope of this snippet is ensure that wordpress is loaded 'WPINC' is better because is more _wordpressfull_ staring with 'WP'.

Answer (score 9):

`if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) die;` and `if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;` add an extra layer of security by preventing any direct access to your plugin file. `ABSPATH` is a PHP constant defined by WordPress in its core.

If your plugin file is accessed from outside of WordPress, the constant `ABSPATH` or `WPINC` will not be defined, so it exits the plugin code, preventing any unauthorized access to your code.

`ABSPATH` and `WPINC` are defined in WordPress core as:

```
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/' );
define( 'WPINC', 'wp-includes' );
```

Both are used for same purpose.

Answer (score 3):

> What are the differences between WPINC and ABSPATH?

You can check yourself. Just [look at `wp-load.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-load.php) on the WordPress mirror on GitHub.

Even a quick glance will show the currently selected answer is no longer correct as to how `ABSPATH` is defined. And if you compare different tags on GitHub you will see the `ABSPATH` definition actually changes over time.

> Which one is the 'right' way to do it?

Given these are used for security, I'd go for `ABSPATH`. Rationale being that `ABSPATH` is not only defined first in the WP bootstrapper, `WPINC` is defined under a conditional in the same file and, as a result, is more likely to experience a future regression.

Also, while not explicitly asked, you provided examples using both `die` and `exit`. According to `devdocs.io`, which draws on official API documentation, `die` is equivalent to [`exit`](http://devdocs.io/php/function.exit), so you could choose either of the two and it won't make a difference.

Both `die` and `exit` accept arguments, so you could consider using them to output some useful information, such as an encrypted version tag or contact information, upon abend, or pass an exit code such as `0` or `-1` for further processing.

Also worth noting is that `wp_die` is a thing too. Not to be confused with the PHP built-ins, but compliments them for use in outputting HTML in addition to plain text and is used liberally throughout the WordPress core currently. Learn [more about `wp_die`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/) on WordPress.org.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be good to note that there is no difference between `die` and `exit`.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795025/what-are-the-differences-in-die-and-exit-in-php

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/270679)